# I am experiencing a path issue in the VS Code terminal with npm

Tags: reactjs, node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, path

My working project is located here:

```
Documents\CoursReact\carsApp\cars.
```

When I run:

cd cars
npm start

I encounter a bunch of problems like:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\secuh\OneDrive\Documents/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory,open 'C:\Users\secuh\OneDrive\Documents\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\secuh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-10T11_45_40_444Z-debug-0.log
```

The VS Code terminal is looking for package.json in the Documents directory. package.json is in cars directory

However, when I run:

```
PS C:\Users\secuh\OneDrive\Documents\CoursReact\carsApp> cd cars 
PS C:\Users\secuh\OneDrive\Documents\CoursReact\carsApp\cars> npm start
```

in the Windows terminal, it works perfectly without any errors, and the page launches. On my other PC, this same process works flawlessly in the VS Code terminal.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: What does the command `pwd` (or `Get-Location`) show you in the VS Code terminal when you get that error?

Comment: PS C:\Users\secuh\OneDrive\Documents\CoursReact\carsApp\cars> pwd

Path
----
C:\Users\secuh\OneDrive\Documents\CoursReact\carsApp\cars

so it's right

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a semi colon between commands like this:

```
cd path; npm start;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Node.js Installation:
Ensure that Node.js is installed on your system, and the path to the Node.js executable is added to your system's PATH variable.

Restart VS Code:
Close and reopen VS Code to make sure any changes to your system's PATH variable are recognized.

Reload the Terminal:
If you've made changes to your environment variables, you might need to restart or reload the integrated terminal in VS Code for the changes to take effect.

Comment: So I need to add the path to Node.js (C:\Program Files\nodejs) to the PATH environment variable?